# Deleting only using MERGE in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I want to delete records from the TARGET_TABLE, which have no corresponding record in the SOURCE_TABLE. In Postgres the following apparently works, whereas in Oracle doesn't:

```
MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE tar
     USING (select s.empno from SOURCE_TABLE s
            left outer join TARGET_TABLE t
            on s.empno=t.empno
            where t.empno is null) src ON (tar.empno = src.empno)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE
```

Is it possible to perform DELETE as the only action when using MERGE in Oracle?

Comment: Why don't you write a simple Delete instead? `delete from TARGET_TABLE tar
     where not exists (select src.empno from SOURCE_TABLE src
    
            where tar.empno = src.empno)`

Comment: Maybe you're right, just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According oracle docs you cant do that

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606)

- Specify the DELETE where_clause to clean up data in a table while
  populating or updating it. The only rows affected by this clause are
  those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge
  operation. The DELETE WHERE condition evaluates the updated value,
  not the original value that was evaluated by the UPDATE SET ... WHERE
  condition. If a row of the destination table meets the DELETE
  condition but is not included in the join defined by the ON clause,
  then it is not deleted. Any delete triggers defined on the target
  table will be activated for each row deletion.

But you can do that using dummy update

```
when matched then update set 1=1
    where -- condition
delete 
    where --condition
```